# javax.el.PropertyNotFoundException JSF 2.1 Apach Tomcat Eclipse Kepler

Tags: jsf, cdi, propertynotfoundexception

I am following some tutorial about Java EE, trying to do an simple example on my own. Even I type exactly the same in my code, it won't work. The difference is (between mine and the example in the tutorial) that i am using `Eclipse Kepler` (not NetBeans) and `Apache Tomcat` (not GlassFish).

**HTTP Status 500 - javax.el.PropertyNotFoundException: Target Unreachable, identifier 'greetingManager' resolved to null**

Here's the code: of the `index.xhtml`:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN"      "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
    xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
    xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core"
    xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets">

<h:head>
    <title>Yo Digga Yo</title>
</h:head>
<h:body>
    <h:form>
        <h:inputText value="#{greetingManager.name}" />
        <h:commandButton action="greet" value="click" />
    </h:form>
</h:body>
</html>
```

that's the `GreetingManager` class:

```
package com.maja.greeting;

import java.io.Serializable;
import javax.enterprise.context.SessionScoped;
import javax.inject.Named;


@Named
@SessionScoped
public class GreetingManager implements Serializable{

    private String name;

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public String getGreeting() {

        return "...";
    }
}
```

ant finally, that's the greet.xhtml:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
    xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
    xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core"
    xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets">

<h:head></h:head>
<h:body>
    <h2>#{greetingManager.greeting}</h2>
</h:body>
</html>
```

I've already imported the required .jar files for the @Named and @SessionScoped annotations, because tomcat doesn't provide them (?)

Ps. This tutorial is about CDI, so I kinda "have to" do this with the @Named Annotation :) And the code is not finished !

Comment: See [How to install CDI in Tomcat?](http://balusc.blogspot.com/2013/10/how-to-install-cdi-in-tomcat.html)

Comment: Where is your *beans.xml*? Do you have `bean-discovery-mode="all"`?

Comment: @kolossus yes, i do. The Problem occurs though :(

Comment: @peeskillet thanks a lot i installed weld in my tomcat and it solved the Problem. Thanks a lot  for the link !

Comment: Yea I wasn't sure if that was the problem or not, that's why I didn't post it as an answer. I'm glad it worked out for you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your greetingManager class should be a managed bean in order to access it from your .xhtml file. To do so, you need to add the

```
@ManagedBean
```

annotation.

Comment: Here I used the Named annotation for: it should be reachable with the Named annotation instead of ManagedBeand too (?) at least it worked for the example I was shown :) :S